# nmap "failed to open output file /home/(user)/file

Tags: ubuntu, nmap

On my new Ubuntu installation, using nmap 7.91, when trying to do a scan with `oN ~/somefile` I always get the error `Failed to open normal output file /home/user/somefile for writing QUITTING!`
I have tried using `sudo`, creating the files beforehand, using absolute paths, explicitly making the file writable using `chmod`, trying the xml and script kiddie formats. Nothing works.

The OS is Ubuntu 20.04 and nmap was installed using snap.
The exact command is

```
sudo nmap -sn -oN /home/user/somefile [some IP range here]
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue today, and it seems to be a change in behavior (or bug) with version 7.91.  To resolve, I removed version 7.91 via snap, then installed the previous version (7.80) with: sudo apt install nmap.  That fixed the problem for me.